# @Html.GlobalisedRouteLink with Image?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, globalization

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 (razor) with globalization.
I have this:

```
 @Html.GlobalisedRouteLink("English", "en", ViewContext.RouteData)
```

How can I replace the word "English" with an image?

thanks

Comment: From which library is this `GlobalisedRouteLink` coming from?

Comment: I am using: MvcGlobalisationSupport, System.Web.Optimization, NavigationRoutes. @nemesv